# Google-maps loads different location from marker

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers

My Google-maps api loads the map on the Atlantic-Ocean whilest my markers are pointed somewhere else.

I have checked my code, the lat and long coordinates are correct and they are marked on the map.

Can anybody help me out on this one?

```
    Dim GeoLatitude As Double
    Dim GeoLongitude As Double
    Dim GoogleGeoCoderKey As String = keyvar
    Dim GoogleResult1 As GoogleResult
    GoogleResult1 = GoogleGeocoder.Geocode("streetname, PC City", GoogleGeoCoderKey) 'CurrentPage.PageName & " " & CurrentPage.BodyLeft
    If GoogleResult1.Status = GeocodeStatus.G_GEO_SUCCESS Then
        If GoogleResult1.Locations.Count = 1 Then
            For Each loc As Location In GoogleResult1.Locations()
                Dim latOld As String = loc.Point.Latitude.ToString()
                GeoLatitude = loc.Point.Latitude ' latOld.Replace(",", ".")
                Dim lonOld As String = loc.Point.Longitude.ToString()
                GeoLongitude = loc.Point.Longitude 'lonOld.Replace(",", ".")
            Next
        End If
    End If
    GoogleMap1.Width = 628
    GoogleMap1.Height = 300
    GoogleMap1.GoogleKey = keyvar
    GoogleMap1.Latitude = GeoLatitude
    GoogleMap1.Longitude = GeoLongitude
    GoogleMap1.Zoom = 15
    GoogleMap1.Options.MapTypes.Add(New Reimers.Map.CustomMaps.GoogleNormalMap())
    Dim tm As New Reimers.Map.CustomMaps.GoogleNormalMap()
    GoogleMap1.DefaultMap() = tm
    GoogleMap1.MapControls.Clear()
    GoogleMap1.MapControls.Add(New Reimers.Map.Controls.GoogleLargeMapControl("smc"))

If SubPagePartValue.SmallText1 <> "" And SubPagePartValue.SmallText2 <> "" Then
              GeoLatitude = CDbl(SubPagePartValue.SmallText1)
                GeoLongitude = CDbl(SubPagePartValue.SmallText2)
            End If
            If GeoLatitude = 0 Or GeoLongitude = 0 Then
                GoogleResult1 = GoogleGeocoder.Geocode(SubPages.BodyLeft, GoogleGeoCoderKey) 
If GoogleResult1.Status = GeocodeStatus.G_GEO_SUCCESS Then
                    If GoogleResult1.Locations.Count = 1 Then
                        For Each loc As Location In GoogleResult1.Locations()
                            Dim latOld As String = loc.Point.Latitude.ToString()
                            GeoLatitude = loc.Point.Latitude
                            Dim lonOld As String = loc.Point.Longitude.ToString()
                            GeoLongitude = loc.Point.Longitude
                            SubPagePartValue.SmallText1 = GeoLatitude
                            SubPagePartValue.SmallText2 = GeoLongitude
                            SubPagePartValue.Save()
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
Dim HTMLCode As String
            Dim gm As GoogleMarker = New GoogleMarker(SubPages.PageID)
            gm.Point.Latitude = GeoLatitude
            gm.Point.Longitude = GeoLongitude
            HTMLCode = "<div class=""GoogleMapsPopUp""><h1 class=""GoogleMapsPopUp"">" & SubPages.PageName & "</h1>"
            HTMLCode = HTMLCode & "<p class=""text""><a href=""" & SubPages.SEOURL(1) & """ title=""" & SubPages.SEOTitleTagLink & """>" & SubPages.PageName & "</a></p><p>" & SubPages.BodyLeft & "</p></div>"
            gm.MarkerText = HTMLCode
            gm.ClientSideHandlers.OnInfoWindowOpen = GoogleMap1.PanTo(gm.Point)
            gm.ClientSideHandlers.OnClick = gm.OpenInfoWindowHTML(GoogleMap1, gm.MarkerText)
            'gm.Options.Icon = SailpointIcon
            gm.Options.Title = Replace(SubPages.PageName, "'", "")
            GoogleMap1.Overlays.Add(gm)
        End If
    Next
```

the actual result can be viewed on the following site: http://www.stripdagenhaarlem.nl/Programma-Stripdagen-Haarlem.html?cb=T If you zoom out on the maps you would see that the markers are placed correct. However, the map keeps zooming on the wrong location.

Comment: pst the code you have in your program , this happened to me a while back too, your missing something thats for sure

Comment: Are your Latitude and Longitude in the correct order?

Comment: Are you sure your bounding box (i.e. view port for the map) have the correct lat/long values and are not reversed?

Comment: @Karl, yes I am sure. Because the markers are placed on the correct cities(in Holland). However, the map zooms on the atlantic ocean

Comment: @404Student - It would help if you posted your code, so we can see where potential issues are.

Comment: @Karl, I have posted it.

Comment: @Pakk I have posted it.

Comment: If you debug your code and put a break point on the lines `GoogleMap1.Latitude = GeoLatitude` and `GoogleMap1.Longitude = GeoLongitude`, what are the values of `GeoLatitude` and `GeoLongitude` at that point?

Comment: @karl this is very odd but it displays 0 for long and 0 for lat. I have given the address now directly as a string format: "Grote Markt 25, 2011 RC, Haarlem" and the problem still remains. Does this mean that the  api can't convert the address to a geoloc?

Comment: @404Student - Yep, that is the problem, it is putting the center of your map at 0,0 which is right off the western coast of Africa.

Comment: @karl Thanks for your feedback. However that isn't the problem either I am getting a error 610 meaning that the GEOkey isn't valid. Kind of strange, because the key was specially generated for this particular website.

Comment: @404Student - The default value for a `Double` is 0, as documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx); therefore if is like you said that an error is happening on retrieving the lat/long values, then it will use the default lat/long of 0,0 and put your map centered off the western coast of Africa.

Answer (score 1):

Try and load your variables to make the code look like

```
<html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=utf-8 /><body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0  ><iframe width=574 height=275 frameborder=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 src=https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=" & GLLat & "," & GLLong & "&amp;spn=0.819443,1.454315&amp;t=h&amp;z=18&amp;output=embed></iframe></body></html>
```

Make sure scrolling=no and z=18, z is the zoom where it initially starts out at

You will have to piece your variables together yourself :P

hope this helps